# React useState not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a description box that can be edited in "edit mode", but just diplays the static definition otherwise.

During edit mode, I want the state to be recorded in the react state "editedHTMLDefinition", before being recorded to the global state when exiting "edit mode".

```
const EditableDescription = ({
  htmlDefinition,
  setHTMLDefinition = () => {},
  editMode,
  word,
}) => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState();
  const [editedHTMLDefinition, setEditedHTMLDefinition] = useState(null);
  const editedHTMLRef = useRef(null);
  // const editorStateRef = useRef(null);

  const onChange = (newEditorState, editor) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
    editor.current = newEditorState;
  };

  const CustomContent = (
    <ContentEditable
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        borderColor: "rgba(255,211,2,0.68)",
        border: "1px solid gray",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        maxWidth: "100%",
        padding: "10px",
      }}
      value={editorState} // Use value prop to set the content
      onChange={onChange} // Handle content changes
    />
  );

  function LoadContentPlugin() {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    editor.update(() => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const dom = parser.parseFromString(htmlDefinition, "text/html");

      // Once you have the DOM instance it's easy to generate LexicalNodes.
      const nodes = $generateNodesFromDOM(editor, dom);
      // Select the root
      const root = $getRoot();
      const paragraphNode = $createParagraphNode();

      nodes.forEach((n) => paragraphNode.append(n));

      root.append(paragraphNode);
    });
  }

  const lexicalConfig = {
    namespace: word,
    onError: (e) => {
      console.log("ERROR:", e);
    },
  };

  const editableDescription = (
    <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <LexicalComposer initialConfig={lexicalConfig}>
        <RichTextPlugin
          contentEditable={CustomContent}
          ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
        />
        <OnChangePlugin
          onChange={(editorState, editor) => {
            editor.update(() => {
              setEditedHTMLDefinition((prevEditedHTMLDefinition) => {
                const newEditedHTMLDefinition = String(
                  $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null)
                );
                console.log(
                  "EDITOR STATE: ",
                  JSON.stringify(editorState),
                  "\nHTML: ",
                  $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null),
                  "\nEdited HTML: ",
                  newEditedHTMLDefinition,
                  "\nprevEditedHTMLDefinition",
                  prevEditedHTMLDefinition
                );
                return newEditedHTMLDefinition;
              });
              editedHTMLRef.current = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null);
            });
          }}
        />
        <HistoryPlugin />
        <LoadContentPlugin />
      </LexicalComposer>
    </div>
  );

  const [descriptionBox, setDescriptionBox] = useState(
    <StaticDescription htmlDefinition={htmlDefinition} />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("editedHTMLDefinition changed: ", editedHTMLDefinition);
  }, [editedHTMLDefinition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Edit mode changed for ", htmlDefinition);
    if (!editMode) {
      // handle save
      console.log("internal edited desc: ", editedHTMLDefinition);
      console.log("ref state: ", editedHTMLRef);
      setHTMLDefinition(editedHTMLDefinition);
      setDescriptionBox(<StaticDescription htmlDefinition={htmlDefinition} />);
    } else {
      // switch to edit mode
      setDescriptionBox(editableDescription);
    }
  }, [editMode]);

  return descriptionBox;
};
```

The issue is, the state is not being recorded as expected. In the first "useEffect" call, as I'm editing, I'm getting the correct values from the state based on what I've written in the box.

However, when I change the editMode, the editedHTMLDefinition gives me "null" as the value (same as its initial state). I tried using a ref instead but I got the same result.

I feel like it might be because editMode is a react state thats being passed in, so maybe the component is rerendering when it changes, so the editedHTMLDefinition also resets. How do I solve this? I want the component to react to when editMode changes

editMode is a higher level state controlled by a single button that's being passed to multiple editableDescriptions at once

Edit: The component where this is being used:

```
function Flashcards() {
  const { collectionName } = useParams();

  // Set a default value of "default_collection" if collectionName is not provided
  const selectedCollection = collectionName
    ? collectionName
    : "default_collection";

  const [flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("flashcards")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flashcards"))
      : []
  );

  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  const toggleEditMode = () => {
    setEditMode(!editMode);
    console.log("Edited edit mode");
  };

  function Flashcard({ index, word, definition }) {
    const wordField = (
      <TextField
        id="outlined-multiline-flexible"
        multiline
        style={{
          flex: "1",
          padding: "10px",
        }}
        value={word}
        disabled={!editMode}
      />
    );

    return (
      <>
        <Box
          key={index}
          sx={{
            boxShadow: "0px 10px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            p: 2,
            borderRadius: 2,
            mt: 3,
            position: "relative",
            display: "flex",
          }}
        >
          {wordField}

          <EditableDescription
            htmlDefinition={definition}
            setHTMLDefinition={(newDef) => {
              console.log("NEW DEFINITION", newDef);
            }}
            editMode={editMode}
          />
        </Box>
      </>
    );
}
  return (
    <>
      <Stack
        sx={{ mb: 2 }}
        direction="row"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="space-between"
      >
        <IconButton to="/" component={Link} sx={{ color: "black", mr: 1 }}>
          <BackIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6">Flashcards</Typography>
        <Button onClick={toggleEditMode} color={editMode ? "success" :"error"}>
          Edit
        </Button>
      </Stack>

      {!!Object.keys(flashcards[selectedCollection]).length ? (
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {Object.keys(flashcards[selectedCollection]).map((index) => {
            const wordInfo = flashcards[selectedCollection][index];
            console.log("Index: ", index, " Wordifo: ", wordInfo);
            const word = wordInfo.word;
            const definition = wordInfo.definition;

            return (
              <Grid item xs={12} key={index}>
                <Flashcard
                  index={index}
                  word={word}
                  definition={definition}
                />
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      ) : (
        <Typography sx={{ mt: 5 }} align="center">
          No Flashcards
        </Typography>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Flashcards;
```

Comment: I fear you are really misunderstanding how to use React. You are storing JSX in component state instead of the data and rendering it to JSX, which is just asking for issues with stale closures over variables. You are also declaring React components inside other React components, the issue here is that these are redeclared each render cycle, so you are needlessly unmounting and remounting them. I didn't dig deeper than this, but I suspect it isn't helping you debug any state management issues.

Comment: See if you can pare this code down to a much simpler [mcve] that demonstrates the state issue so readers here don't need to wade through all the other React issues and anti-patterns in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const EditableDescription = ({
  htmlDefinition,
  setHTMLDefinition = () => {},
  editMode,
  word,
}) => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState();
  const [editedHTMLDefinition, setEditedHTMLDefinition] = useState(null);
  const editedHTMLRef = useRef(null);
  const [descriptionBox, setDescriptionBox] = useState(
    <StaticDescription htmlDefinition={htmlDefinition} />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect will run when editMode changes
    if (editMode) {
      // If entering edit mode, set the editable description
      setDescriptionBox(
        <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
          {/* Your LexicalComposer and plugins here */}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      // If exiting edit mode, save the edited HTML definition
      setHTMLDefinition(editedHTMLRef.current);
      setDescriptionBox(<StaticDescription htmlDefinition={htmlDefinition} />);
    }
  }, [editMode]);

  const onChange = (newEditorState, editor) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
    editor.current = newEditorState;

    setEditedHTMLDefinition($generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null));
    editedHTMLRef.current = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {descriptionBox}
      <ContentEditable
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,211,2,0.68)",
          border: "1px solid gray",
          borderRadius: "5px",
          maxWidth: "100%",
          padding: "10px",
        }}
        value={editorState}
        onChange={onChange}
        disabled={!editMode} // Disable the editor when not in edit mode
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditableDescription;
```

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to work, and I'm still running into the same issue. I used a useEffect hook to check the state of the ref and useState, and they record the changes correctly. However, once I change the edit mode, both of them just return their initial starting values.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to reduce the uses of `useState` with `useEffect` if possible.

Here, rather than using `useEffect` with `editMode`, take `editMode` from the props and use it as conditional rendering like below -

```
    return (
        editMode
            ? <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
                <LexicalComposer initialConfig={lexicalConfig}>
                <RichTextPlugin
                    contentEditable={CustomContent}
                    ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
                />
                <OnChangePlugin ... />
                <HistoryPlugin />
                <LoadContentPlugin />
                </LexicalComposer>
            </div>
            : <StaticDescription htmlDefinition={htmlDefinition} />
    )
```

So, based on `editMode`, it will render the JSX conditionally.

Also, can you add the  Component too?

Comment: I've added the component where this is being used to the question

I was going to initially do what you are suggesting, but how would I add the logic of saving the edits when the editMode changes? That's why I was using useEffect

Comment: Conditional rendering didn't work either, I ended up getting an infinite loop of component rerenders for some reason